# Latest Camera Permission in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

private fun showImagePicDialog() {
val options = arrayOf("Take Photo", "Take Video", "Choose Photo", "Choose Video")
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
builder.setTitle("Pick Post From...")
builder.setItems(options) { dialog, which ->
when (which) {
0 -> takePhoto()
1 -> takeVideo()
2 -> choosePhoto()
3 -> chooseVideo()
}
}
builder.create().show()
}

```
private fun takePhoto() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000)
}

private fun takeVideo() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1001)
}

private fun choosePhoto() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    cameraIntent.type = "image/*"
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1002)
    }
}

private fun chooseVideo() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.type = "video/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1003)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (requestCode) {

        1000 -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                takePhotoBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as? Bitmap
                if (takePhotoBitmap != null) {
                    binding.sImgUploadPost.setImageBitmap(takePhotoBitmap)
                }
            } else {
                requireContext().showToast("Photo capture was canceled or failed")
            }
        }

        1001 -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                takeVideoURI = data?.data
                if (takeVideoURI != null) {
                    // Handle the captured video URI
                    // For example, you can display it in a VideoView
                    binding.sVidUploadPost.setVideoURI(takeVideoURI)
                    binding.sVidUploadPost.start()
                }
            } else {
                // Video recording was canceled or failed
                requireContext().showToast("Video recording was canceled or failed")
            }
        }

        1002 -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {
                choosePhotoURI = data?.data

                if (choosePhotoURI != null) {
                    Glide.with(this).load(choosePhotoURI).centerCrop()
                        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                        .into(binding.sImgUploadPost)
                }
            } else {
                requireContext().showToast("Photo selection was canceled or failed")
            }
        }

        1003 -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {
                chooseVideoURI = data?.data
                if (chooseVideoURI != null) {
                    // Handle the selected video URI
                    // For example, you can display it in a VideoView
                    binding.sVidUploadPost.setVideoURI(chooseVideoURI)
                    binding.sVidUploadPost.start()
                }
            } else {
                requireContext().showToast("Video selection was canceled or failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

startActivityForResult and super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) is deprecated can please solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private val takePictureLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // The photo was captured and saved successfully
                // Display the captured image in your ImageView
                appCompatImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath))
            } else {
                // Photo capture failed or was canceled
                Toast.makeText(this, "Photo capture failed or was canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        }

private val pickImageLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
            val selectedImageUri: Uri? = result.data?.data
            if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                // Set the selected image to the ImageView
                appCompatImageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image selection canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

private val takeVideoLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Video recording was successful
            val videoUri = result.data?.data
            if (videoUri != null) {
                setVideoToVideoView(videoUri)
            }
        } else {
            // Video recording failed or was canceled
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording failed or was canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

private val pickVideoLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { videoUri ->
        if (videoUri != null) {
            // Set the selected video to the VideoView
            appCompatVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri)
            appCompatVideoView.start()
        }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    takePicture = findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture)
    appCompatImageView = findViewById(R.id.appCompatImageView)
    choosePicture = findViewById(R.id.btnChoosePicture)
    takeVideo = findViewById(R.id.btnTakeVideo)
    appCompatVideoView = findViewById(R.id.appCompatVideoView)
    btnChooseVideo = findViewById(R.id.btnChooseVideo)

    takePicture.setOnClickListener {

        if (!hasPermissions(this, *REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, ALL_PERMISSIONS)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All Permissions Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ startCamera() }, 1000)
        }
    }

    choosePicture.setOnClickListener {

        val galleryIntent =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        pickImageLauncher.launch(galleryIntent)
    }

    takeVideo.setOnClickListener {

        if (!hasPermissions(this, *REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, ALL_PERMISSIONS)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All Permissions Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startVideoRecording()
        }
    }

    btnChooseVideo.setOnClickListener {
        pickVideoLauncher.launch("video/*")
    }

}

private fun startVideoRecording() {
    if (!isRecording) {
        val videoFile = createTempVideoFile()
        videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this, "com.example.makecameraapplication.provider", videoFile
        )
        val videoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri)
        takeVideoLauncher.launch(videoIntent)
        isRecording = true
    } else {
        stopVideoRecording()
    }
}

private fun stopVideoRecording() {
    isRecording = false
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun createTempVideoFile(): File {
    val timeStamp: String = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
    val storageDir: File? =
        getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) // Store in Movies directory
    return File.createTempFile(
        "VIDEO_${timeStamp}_", ".mp4", storageDir
    ).apply {
        currentVideoPath = absolutePath
    }
}


private fun setVideoToVideoView(videoUri: Uri) {
    appCompatVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(currentVideoPath))
    appCompatVideoView.start()
}


private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean =
    permissions.all {
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

private fun createTempImageFile(): File {
    val timeStamp: String = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(null)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", ".jpg", storageDir
    ).apply {
        currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
    }
}

private fun startCamera() {
    val imageFile = createTempImageFile()
    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        this, "com.example.makecameraapplication.provider", imageFile
    )
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
    takePictureLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)
}

private fun finishActivity() {
    Toast.makeText(
        this, "You must grant all required permissions to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()/* finish()*/
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when (requestCode) {
        ALL_PERMISSIONS -> {
            if (grantResults.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                finishActivity()
            }
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    const val ALL_PERMISSIONS = 10
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = mutableListOf(
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ).apply {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, welcome to SO. Please explain your answer.

Comment: Can you write an explanation about your code?

Answer (score 0):

As per Android 13 and developer guideline [Reference Link Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions), you will need to request for Granular Media Permissions **(READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)**  for corresponding file access.

About ***startActivityForResult*** being deprecated, you will need to request for permission using **ActivityResultLauncher** [Reference Link1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin) and [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

```
// Register the permissions callback, which handles the user's response to the
// system permissions dialog. Save the return value, an instance of
// ActivityResultLauncher. You can use either a val, as shown in this snippet,
// or a lateinit var in your onAttach() or onCreate() method.
val requestPermissionLauncher =
registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
        // app.
    } else {
        // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
        // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
        // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
        // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
        // decision.
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
   // request for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES using ActivityResultLauncher
else 
  //request for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE using startActivityForResult
```

Also, to be able to use ActivityResultLauncher make sure you are using required appcompat version

**build.gradle (app-level)**

```
  val appcompat_version = "1.6.1"
  implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version")
```